# Google Analytics embed API does not load because of content security policy error

Tags: google-analytics, content-security-policy

I've copied the exact Google's example code for embedding the Google Analytics API from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started

And what my browser says is:

> Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src:
>   ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)
>
> Content Security Policy:
>   Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified 
>   (unknown)
>
> Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src:
>   ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)

I've tried it both on my http localhost, and a https domain on a web server, with the same result.

The actual code below step 2 is not needed to replicate the issue, only adding their script to the document already causes that error to appear. So the error is not in any way connected to a specific Google account or an API key.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>

<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't say anywhere on that page or the documentation that this code is deprecated, or old, or not valid anymore. But the script file is just refused, and I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the code, this rather seems to have to do with your server's configuration.

Content Security policies are designed to prevent (among other things) XSS attacks, and they to this by preventing scripts from unknown sources to be executed or to be dynamically inserted. Since the embed API relies on inline script, remote code injection and other techniques also employed by malware it is blocked by the CSP.

CSPs are set a a http header by the server, so you'd need to talk to whoever manages your server for you. Most likely he or she will not simply remove a security feature, which would mean that you cannot use the embed API.

There is no way (that I know of) to make inline script and code injection safe. Changing the CSP to allow inline scripting will simply remove all protection it might else offer.

Answer (score 0):

If your Content Security Policy contains 'strict-dynamic' then your server likely also creates a random, per-response `nonce` value and puts it into the `Content-Security-Policy` response header.

To make the Analytics script block run you have to insert the same value as an attribute of the `<script>` element, e.g.

```
<script nonce="{{ csp_nonce }}">
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){ ... }(window,document,'script'));
</script>
```

(where `csp_nonce` has to be replaced by the random value by your template system; the name of the variable and interpolation syntax depend on your server-side configuration.)

Alternatively, to allow a static `<script>` block to run you can use a [CSP2 hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script). You can find the SHA256 hash of your script by copying its contents into https://report-uri.com/home/hash and add this value to `script-src` in your CSP header.